# Max sum of vectors choosen from points on circles

Tags: geometry, algorithms, vectors, circles

What is an algorithm that solves this problem: Given N circles (defined by center coords and radius), what is the maximum vector sum of points, choosing one point from each circle.  Note that the circles may have different radii, may overlap, may be the same or different, etc.

For example, given circles  c=(-10,0)r=1 and c=(10,0)r=1, the answer is 2 (choosing the point closest to the origin from one circle, and furthest on the other - summing them yields a vector with abs val 2).  Choosing the furthest on each circle would cancel each other out.

Intuitively, I suspect the answer could be:
1. Take the vector sum of the centers of all the circles = V1. This vector is in the same direction as the desired result vector.
2. For each circle, choose the point that is in that direction from its center.  I.e. choose the point  (center + radius * normalized(V1))
3. Sum these points to yield the answer

But I am in no way certain and unsure how to prove it's correct (if it is correct)

(This is my first question on this site, please be gentle - let me know how I can improve this question)

Comment: If you choose a direction -- say, $\varphi$ counterclockwise from the positive $x$ axis --, and for each circle, pick a point in that direction from the center of that circle, isn't the vector sum then $\lVert \sum_{i} \vec{v}_i \rVert = \sum_{i} r_i$, i.e. length equal to the sum of the circles radiuses, regardless of the direction $\varphi$? (The direction of the sum vector, of course, would be $\varphi$, though.)

Comment: note that we're also adding the circle center, so it's not just the sum of radius vectors, i.e. center + radius * normalized(V1)   instead of  just   radius * normalized(V1)

Comment: Ah; so the summed vectors are from origin to a point on each circle. Right. To prove your answer, split the result into two parts: the sums of the vectors from origin to the center of each circle, and the sums of the vectors from circle centers to points on the circumference. The former is fixed; there is nothing you can do about it. The latter, as I mentioned in my first comment, reaches its maximum length when all latter vectors point in the same direction $\varphi$. The final thing to note is that the two parts' sum reaches a maximum, when they both are oriented in the same direction.